# three.js css3d panorama stop animation on load

Tags: three.js

I'm using three.js css3d panorama and I would like to stop animation on load. I want a static panomara on load and it moves only throw user action. How can I do that?

the code i'm using is the same on example http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_panorama:

```
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    lon +=  0.1;
    lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
    phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
    theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

    target.x = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
    target.y = Math.cos( phi );
    target.z = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

    camera.lookAt( target );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );  

}
```

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Heres your problem below:

```
  lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
  phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
  theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

  target.x = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
  target.y = Math.cos( phi );
  target.z = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
```

You see the above lines animating your camera.

```
 camera.lookAt( target ); //  see the importance
```

Camera is looking at the target, from what I see is the targetx,y,z position has animation applied over time: `target.z = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin`
and than your renderer is rendering the scene -> your camera -> your target.